# I can't find a suitable api to implement a chat in my app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'd like to implement an authentic chat feature in my app built with react-native + expo and i've tried to create a homemade one with push notifications + firebase database but the result is below my expectations.Althought it's working, it's very slow to load and my app crashes and generates a lot of bad errors. I can't release an app with such a poor performances.

I need to find a better solution.

I've checked `pubnub chat engine` and `pusher chat kit` but i can't find an answer to one question : How can i list (with pagination) every channel (conversation) in order to make a whatsapp-like inbox view which list all my  last conversation with unread badges and displaying the last message and user photo etc.

Can someone advise me about how to organize this ?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two parts: inbox listing for each user and realtime chatting.

The inbox listing is stored in app local, maybe sqlite. You may have a table message with: message_id, sender, message_text, received_time, read_time. ..

A simple real-time chatting can be achieved by publishing and subscribing to MessageQueue.

Every app(user) will subscribe to his own topic when connected to your server.  When your server receives a new message, it will check whether the receiver is online and if yes, it will directly publish the message to his topic. The client app will receive the message since it have subscribed, and store the message locally. The unread badge is tracked locally.

For messagequeue, you actually can just use cloud service. AWS has ActiveMQ and IoT message broker. The communication is via MQTT over Websocket.

Comment: thanks for your reply. However i need my chat to be stored 100% in the cloud. How do instagram to make their inbox listing and chat conversation immediately available as soon as i tap the screen . Even after i totally clear the instagram data, all instagram chat conversations were already in my app when i got back in there.

Comment: I see, that's different from WhatsApp mentioned in the OP. If so, you must persist the chat history in the server. Redis (aws elastic cache) has persistent message queue. (I didn't try before)

Comment: Another option (doable) is to store all messages in dynamodb. When you app  first installed, you need fetch from there.